# What do I need to do to use my current recipe for thin-crust pizza?

Tags: dough, pizza

When I make pizza dough, I use a variation on [Bobby Flay's recipe](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/bobby-flay/pizza-dough-recipe) - instead of 3.5 - 4 cups of bread flour I use 2 cups of bread flour, 3/4 cup AP, and 3/4 cup white wheat, with maybe a touch more AP if the dough is too wet. I also use AP when kneading. This makes 2 ~14" pizzas for me, which means a fairly thick crust - especially at the edges, which can get 1" or higher after cooking.

I make 14" pizzas largely because that's the size stone I have, but also because I can't get the dough to stretch much more without tearing. If I want to make slightly larger / thinner pizzas, do I need to modify the recipe? Is there a difference between thin-crust recipes and thick-crust recipes (and deep-dish)? Or is it a matter of technique before / while shaping the dough? Could I use this to make a truly thin crust pizza, or would I need an entirely different recipe?

Edit: The suggested [duplicate](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/10261/tips-to-make-pizza-dough-workable) is similar, but in my case the dough is able to be shaped exactly how the recipe indicates - yielding 2 ~14" pizzas. I do not have problems working it to get the yield specified by the recipe, but am instead interested in using this same recipe to make more and/or bigger (thinner) pizzas.

Comment: I think you might get a variety of answers here, as people develop and maintain strong preferences about their pizzas.  From my own experience, I typically make Neapolitan style, thin crust, hand formed pizza.  I have successfully put the same dough in a sheet pan, pressed out by hand, and created a thick crust pizza.  Of course there is more dough (it is thicker) in the sheet pan.  I also let it rise again while in the pan, before topping and baking.  See also: question 10261 (type the number in the search bar)....and 10273...I think we may have to close because your answers are elsewhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tips To Make Pizza Dough Workable](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/10261/tips-to-make-pizza-dough-workable)

Comment: I don't agree this is a duplicate of the workable dough question. The answers will have similar information but the question seems very different to me.

Comment: @moscafj edited to highlight differences with suggested duplicate

Comment: If you aren't using all bread flour you will have less gluten, which will give you a lower limit of how stretchy your dough can be. You need to develop all the gluten you can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tl;Dr Yes, let it rest

It is going to be difficult to give you a perfectly canonical answer to this question because, as moscafj commented, there is a lot of variation in pizza recipes.

**Dough Recipes**

Thin crust pizza dough, such as the popular Neapolitan style, is typically made with high protein dough. Your recipe, before your modifications, called for 100% bread flour and would definitely fall in this category. If there isn't enough protein thin crusts will not have the structure to stay together when sliced.

Thick crust dough can get away with a little less protein because they have more space for structure. The less protein the more the crust will be bready instead of chewy.

There are, of course, many other variables that make the difference between thin and thick, for example; thin crusts are often baked at higher temps. In general a good pizza dough recipe can be used for either.

Your recipe, including your modifications, is very similar to the recipe I use and I have had good success with both thin and thicker (I never go thicker than .5") pizzas.

**Getting it thin**

With all bread dough- especially high protein doughs- as you work the dough the gluten gets very tight. All bread recipes have resting periods for the dough to relax before it is shaped.

If you are using that much bread flour, you should be able to get your dough so thin that light will shine through.

If you can't get there because the dough isn't smooth and just comes apart then you don't have good gluten development.
See one of the many questions here on that subject.

If you can't because the dough is too stiff then you might be working in too much flour and you should learn to work with wetter dough.

If you can't because the proteins are too tight and snap back then let the dough rest a little longer.

Comment: >  If there isn't enough protein thin crusts will not have the structure to stay together when sliced. - I disagree here. Many European countries don't have flours with different protein content, and happily make thin pizza crusts with AP-equivalent flour. It works well enough.